# How to create the small triangle on chest

Tags: workout, chest

I want to create the small triangle on my chest.It is between the two pecs.In the image the two black marks i mesn.Thank you a lot
[image]

Comment: Unless you know the correct terminology, it's usually best to provide a picture so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: OK I upload a picture

Comment: That's the xiphisternum. It's the bottom part of the sternum. It's a bone, and not a muscle, so it's not something you develop. I'm afraid we're limited by genetics there.

Comment: Maybe , the muscles lines on left and the right pec,those in will edit

Comment: On the close votes, no idea how it is "unclear what he's asking". He's even drew a picture for us. Maybe you don't like the question, but I can't see this being a clarity issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While genetics does play a part in how your muscles develop, it is not the only factor.  You may not achieve the exact features you're looking for, but, there's nothing stopping you from building a better looking chest.  The first thing to remember is never let anyone tell you you can't improve a particular body part.  You'll never know unless you try.

As a former competitive body builder, I often looked for exercises that would add that finishing touch to my chest before competition.  More often than not, this would mean adding isolation movements to my competition routine.  This often meant using the [pec deck](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/LVPecDeckFly.html), or, doing dumbbell flyes.  In fact, a [2012 study](https://www.acefitness.org/certifiednewsarticle/2884/ace-sponsored-research-top-3-most-effective-chest) funded by the [American Council on Exercise](https://www.acefitness.org/) found that the peck deck was nearly as effective as the bench press in activating the pectoralis major, one of the major muscle groups in the chest and in the picture you show.

> “Both the pec deck (at 98% of muscle activation compared to barbell
>   bench press) and the bent-forward cable crossover (93% of muscle
>   activation) elicited nearly equivalent muscle activation as the
>   barbell bench press. “

So, while you may not achieve the exact look of that picture, there are a myriad of effective exercises to get you closer to achieving your goal.

Comment: This is basically the longer version of what I said.

Comment: Maybe, but it's likely the OP probably doesn't have the muscle mass there either.  Your answer comes at it with the perspective that "no, it can't be done" which is true, but this answer adds context that it's the shape that can't be changed, whereas the first step is just to build muscle mass.

Answer (score 2):

This is purely genetics. The only thing you can do is develop your chest to make it show more, but you cannot change the shape itself.

Comment: You sure that those black marks can't get shown ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with MJB, you can do the exact exercises as the the guy in the picture, but depending on your genetics, you might never have that shaped chest, you might not even have a flat chest, it might be bulky and round because that is your body compesision.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for me - this is purely genetics. Shape of muscle, how it it attached, is "defined" by your genetics. You can train to have bigger pecs, or go down with fat. That way you can make things like that visible, but shape - that is out of control. Go to google type 'pectoralis body building' and see how many different shapes are there. All that chest are great, yet different.

Comment: All muscles are shaped exactly the same for most human beings, different shapes in muscles means some people would not be ever able to do certain movements and everyone  would do the same exercise differently based on the shape of their muscles. Which isn't the case.

Comment: Yes, and no. There are people that have 4 muscles at biceps. Some of black people has additional pair of muscles at chest. Some has muscle at wrist, used to fix fingers... So even if we talk about set of muscles we can be different. Calves, and mentioned biceps - some of us has it longer, some shorter. To mention obvious ones. Chest is not an exception.